# Android-x86 power button press does not sleep

Tags: 7.1-nougat, android-x86, standby, sleep, power-options

I'm running Android-x86 on an intel Apollo Lake tablet. When I press the power button, Android does not go to sleep. Instead, it shows the power menu. This means I cannot put the device to sleep by pressing the button. Also, there is no option to configure Buttons in Settings.

Sleep works if I open a terminal and type

```
echo mem > /sys/power/state
```

How do I make a single press of the power button put the device to sleep?

Comment: Make sure you're not pressing it for too long